# TV Series about boy who Travels to Parallel World

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe

School trip goes to mountains to watch full solar eclipse. Group of friends, 2 boys and a girl goes to mountains at night.

Boys want to play prank on girl and hang steel cable across rock face.
At some point, a portal opens here. 1 boy walks through it.

He finds a huge steel and concrete tower with some radio in the middle of it. He takes it and gets chased by a man with a stick

Next day he meets a girl in the forest.
The eclipse starts and she accuses him of stealing the sun.
She runs away and leaves some goods behind.
He follows her and comes to some market, where trade is done by barter.

He is found by the market's overseer or ruler.
She shoots him with an electric bolt that looks like ball lightning.
He runs away and meets girl again.
They hear noise above. Boy looks up and sees some huge flying ship.

Boy makes gun powder to scare away Wild Men.
Village owner sends him to the tower.
Flying ship arrives and he goes on it to where rules live.

I missed most episodes of it.

Parallel world where rulers live in the castle in the middle of the forest.
Their castle has electric lighting, fitted bathrooms, and other things of civilization.

- They wear some Electric armor that is Black and Gold in color.
- Fly in huge rusty ships using anti-gravity.
- The ships are powered by some underground generator that shoots bolts out of the tower of the castle.
  Shoots into the sky. Looks like Tesla Tower build on Long Island.
- Ships powered up by wireless energy.
  Every village in the area has its own relay tower.
- Village elder has a radio device called The Voice.
  He installs it on a shelf on the tower and can talk with the castle using radio waves.
- Rulers have wireless energy, lighting, anti-gravity ships, and radio.
- Villagers live in like in middle ages, use hand tools to work fields.
- Village elder tells everyone one night to stay at home as magicians will use magic to deal with some pests that have infected the fields.
- A boy goes here at night and tells the girl that their "magic" is just pesticides they spray from passing ships.
- Rulers are what is left of their ancient country destroyed by nuclear war or something

I briefly saw another series with the same parallel world idea.
Chinese actors in that one.
Girl and Chinese guy using a ship that jumps between parallel worlds
I saw some of the cast from the first series in the second one.
The second one might be season 2.

The first world has a town full of child-crazy immortals, that are served by faceless robots that look like mannequins.

The second had primitive life that was left after a global war. Chinese guy activates some artificial intelligence machine
that goes on a rampage. The machine is called MOLOG and looks like a Russian BTR with 3 energy cannons.

Third looks like ancient China, but has electricity and a central super-computer named Oracle.
Oracle creates huge 3-D projections that fire energy bolts.
Oracle breaks down and the place gets invaded by barbarians.

Comment: No, I this it is season 2 of the first series. If it is season 2 with some what different contents - is it not still classed as the same series?

Comment: Yes, if these are different seasons from the same show, then that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)).

It matches everything you have described. It seems that they are trying to prank one of the girls with a fake ghost on a wire when a portal opens and the boy falls through it.

It should be available to stream on Netflix, at least in Australia.